# Play an audio in conference room on key press by participant in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, dtmf, elastix

I have created a conference room in asterisk via confbridge.conf. Now, I want an audio file to be played to all participants in conference room when any participant press a key. I am not sure how to do that. Any help?

Answer (score -2):

There is no option like that, but you can use "leave_conference" option, trigger some action like new call which deliver your sound file to conference user, after that return to conference.

Require advanced level of coding/asterisk experience.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ConfBridge+Configuration

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out+deliver+message

Comment: thank you for your answer. but just tell me how to make new call to conference room? since I want my message be played to all users in the room. should I put room number as extension to call?

Comment: Check second link